# How could you use dependency injection to inject an Angular Pipe?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have two fully independent host Components that both use the same common Component. The common component uses an Angular Pipe, but I want to use dependency injection to provide a different implementation of the Pipe in each host Component.

It doesn't seem like this is possible - I can only make a Pipe visible to the common Component by adding it to its `imports` array, which makes it the same for both host Components.

In my example, I've injected a `SAMPLE_DEPENDENCY` that shows a different value depending on the host Component, but the `SAMPLE_PIPE` doesn't do anything, nor do the imports at the host Component level. Is it impossible to make a pipe dynamic like this?

**HostComponent1**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SAMPLE_DEPENDENCY, SAMPLE_PIPE } from './tokens';
import { CommonComponent } from './commonComponent';
import { SamplePipe1 } from './pipe1';

@Component({
  selector: 'hostComponent1',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, CommonComponent, SamplePipe1],
  providers: [
    { provide: SAMPLE_DEPENDENCY, useValue: 'SampleValue1' },
    { provide: SAMPLE_PIPE, useClass: SamplePipe1 },
  ],
  template: `<commonComponent></commonComponent>`,
})
export class HostComponent1 {}
```

**HostComponent2**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SAMPLE_DEPENDENCY, SAMPLE_PIPE } from './tokens';
import { CommonComponent } from './commonComponent';
import { SamplePipe2 } from './pipe2';

@Component({
  selector: 'hostComponent2',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, CommonComponent, SamplePipe2],
  providers: [
    { provide: SAMPLE_DEPENDENCY, useValue: 'SampleValue2' },
    { provide: SAMPLE_PIPE, useClass: SamplePipe2 },
  ],
  template: `<commonComponent></commonComponent>`,
})
export class HostComponent2 {}
```

**CommonComponent**

```js
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SAMPLE_DEPENDENCY } from './tokens';
import { SamplePipe1 } from './pipe1';
import { SamplePipe2 } from './pipe2';

@Component({
  selector: 'commonComponent',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    // SamplePipe1,
    // SamplePipe2,
  ],
  template: `
    <p>{{ sampleDependency }}</p>
    <p>{{ 'Sample Input!' | samplePipe }}</p>
  `,
})
export class CommonComponent {
  sampleDependency = inject(SAMPLE_DEPENDENCY);
}
```

The pipe code isn't all that important, but I've created a working example StackBlitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3wec3z?file=src%2FcommonComponent.ts, where if you uncomment `SamplePipe1` or `SamplePipe2` in `CommonComponent`, the app works.